# Xcode Project stuck "Compiling Swift source files"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

My Xcode project had decided not to build and simple get stuck on "Compiling Swift source files". I'm running a completely Swift project with CocoaPods. I've tried clearing all derived data, cleaning the project, and restarting my computer. I've had no luck. I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. If anyone has any ideas to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was in a complicated dictionary. I was creating a big dictionary for JSON parsing tests and the compiling never finished.

When I split the big dictionary into smaller pieces, everything worked OK.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answer for me, but it helps me identify the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. What was the issue?

Comment: It was related to a dictionary, which I was setting the `text` property from an `UITextField`, but I was not unwrapping the optional value. I think that from the dictionary structure Swift compiler inferred it was `[String: String]`, so the optional was confusing the compiler.