# Compiling Swift source files stuck xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to archive my recent app . I am using xcode 7.3.1 and the code is mostly in swift. It runs on simulator , no issues in that. When I try to archive it , it stucks in compiling swift source files. I have tried solutions like restarting the xcode , mac ,cleaning it , derived data deleting. But no matter what I do , it doesn't compile.

Is there any way to debug this ?[image: image of xcode]

Note : I have two xcodes installed 8.1 and 7.3.1. It used to work earlier with both installed in system.

Comment: Try to turn off optimization. Build settings -> OptimizationLevel -> None

Comment: @alexburtnik tried this one too doesn't work

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36066756/1689376

Comment: @va05 what's the version of swift?

Comment: @aircraft swift 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I figured it out. Here is the code which was culprit -

```
func getReferralValueToShow() -> Double
    {
        var valueToReturn = self.referral % 25
        if self.referral<25
        {
            valueToReturn = self.referral
        }
        else
        {
            valueToReturn = 25
        }

        if priceSubTotal() < Double(valueToReturn)        {
            return a
        }
        else
        {
            return Double(valueToReturn)
        }


    }
    func priceSubTotal() -> Double {
        return quantities.reduce(0, combine: { (t, q) in t + q.totalPrice })
    }
```

Here is code that worked

```
 func getReferralValueToShow() -> Double
{
    var valueToReturn = self.referral % 25
    if self.referral<25
    {
        valueToReturn = self.referral
    }
    else
    {
        valueToReturn = 25
    }
    let a = priceSubTotal()
    if a < Double(valueToReturn)        {
        return a
    }
    else
    {
        return Double(valueToReturn)
    }


}
func priceSubTotal() -> Double {
    return quantities.reduce(0, combine: { (t, q) in t + q.totalPrice })
}
```

The problem was to call priceSubTotal in if statement , I hope it helps anyone.